Can a ship like Starship roll during re-entry?
Theoretically can a ship like Starship rotate on its axis (roll) during reentry to spread the heat on the whole surface instead of just one side with the heat shield?
Is it doable? Does it make sense?
Sorry for the uninformed question

I've heard of barbeque rolls during Apollo flights to the Moon but never during re-entry, what an interesting idea!

It certainly works in Kerbal Space Program. Though it also highlights one difficulty: It makes directional control basically impossible.

Reminds me of the joke about how black boxes are made to survive an airliner crash, so why don't we make the whole airliner out of that stuff?

All the answers say that this would be a bad idea, and I'm inclined to agree. But imagine if somebody had asked here a while back: "Why does a rocket need legs to land? Why can't it just be caught out of the sky as it lands?" I suspect the answers would have been just as negative!

I see the comment about bbq roll of apollo.  I worked on that in the early 60s.  That solution was laid out because thermal analysis of the service module propulsion system showed that as a solution to potential propellant freezing in the SM main engine valve.  Any freezing of fuel or ox could prevent the main service module engine from starting when needed.

@tckosvic How old are you !!! ? :-) . I just turned 74 yesterday. You must be older.

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that in general it will not be helpful. I think it's possible to design a vehicle where it would be, but

the mass of the heat shield has now increased by roughly 2x, likely more, to allow for the additional heat loading in all roll orientations

the extra heat shielding also adds complications:  where do you place nozzles for thrusters?  Where are your radiating surfaces for thermal control now?  Where do you place windows for vision or sensors?

control is now more complicated during the descent (though not impossibly so), requiring maintaining roll rate to within a particular range likely in addition to maintaining an overall angle-of-attack and being able to control that angle-of-attack throughout the roll envelope

for Starship specifically, you're likely now forcing comms handoff between multiple Starlink antennas on the vehicle, which are also likely buried under heat shielding that is gradually getting very hot


In much more general terms, every design is a tradeoff between factors. I can't definitively say no re-entry vehicle would benefit from a uniform heat-soak owing to a controlled barbecue roll. But there are design and operational benefits to having fixed windward and leeward sides that I can't see the uniform heating overwhelming, at least for all the spacecraft I'm picturing.

You would need to increase the overall coverage of the heat shielding but, since the load is spread and each part of the craft is now heated less (is that the case???), couldn't the depth of the shielding be reduced?

@DaveGremlin detailed heat shield design isn't my specialty, but my gut feeling is that you're definitely not going to get away with something like simply spreading the original heat shield mass over the entire surface. Maybe it could be thinner (depending on the speed of the roll?) but I'd assume it still has to be substantial enough to withstand the unchanged re-entry heat flux it's getting exposed to without burn-through.

Thanks! I don't know much about spacecraft, didn't think of any of these things, makes sense

@DaveGremlin due to the need of attachment, substructure and especially the non-linear scalings of insultion, your benefits of thinness would be far outweighed by needing more area of shielding. Twice the thickness of (regular building)  insulation isn't twice but (roughly) four times as effective

@Hobbamok  Yes, I think there would be issues with catchments, thruster nozzles, radiators etc.  I just wondered if a factor of 2x for heat shielding would be required.

@DaveGremlin the 2x was just an example of non-linerar scaling. If you need, let's say one tenth of the thermal insulation (by number), you'd still need significantly more than 1/10th of the thickness/weight per area to achieve that, so little to no savings in that regard . And that's ignoring all the other issues that you mentioned

There's also the fact that if you require constant roll to avoid exceeding the heat shield's limits, then you have introduced a new failure mode (failure to roll) with a non-trivial likelihood and a catastrophic outcome. It may even require more redundancy on the roll control systems which tend to eliminate any benefits gained.

There would also be a great deal of difficulty in maintaining the angle of attack. Presumably all of the fins would have to be removed, but it is not clear what would take their place.

@Slarty Yeah, the aero surfaces were my first thought. If you roll 90 degrees, you've got one set of fins sticking down into airflow, and the other set sticking up into the relatively low-pressure area in the ship's shadow.  That's going to make it very difficult to control.

@DaveGremlin a good percentage of the mass of the heat shield isn't the shield material itself but the mounting brackets, spacers, and things like that. While the mass of the shield wouldn't maybe be doubled it would go up substantially.

If a vehicle is to be passively/heat sink cooled rotating it during heating may spread heat load around in a useful way. This requires a design that accepts all/most of the heat energy into the vehicle.
Note that for spacecraft re-entry, the careful design of the shape allows most of the heating to actually happen in the air away from the vehicle surface, not to the heat shield itself. This drastically reduces the needed heatshield system mass, but does mean there is a desired angle and orientation for entry that should be maintained, and therefore having a 'hot side' and a 'really hot side' asymmetric heat shield makes sense. This also allows placing high risk plumbing connections, antenna hatches etc on the cooler side where they both have a lower temperature exposure and also much lower dynamic pressure forcing hot reactive gasses into seals etc.

+1 for mentioning the benefit of having some lower temperature areas designated for more delicate gear

Answer: Bad idea. Redistributing the same mass of insulation and rolling the spacecraft would approximately double the heat conducted through the insulation.
According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_insulation thermal conductivity is proportional to both Temperature Difference and Surface Area, but inversely proportional to Insulator Thickness.
Compare two cylinders of similar dimension with the same mass of insulation.
Cylinder A (not spinning) has both the heat exposure and insulation on the same side.
Cylinder B  is spinning rotisserie fashion. Insulation is half the thickness of cylinder A, but exposed area is twice as much. Any location on B is exposed to heat only half the time, so (as an approximation) the temperature difference averages half as much.
Comparing A and B, surface area and insulator thickness cancel out leaving twice the conductivity due to greater surface area.
The story would be different if the insulation on B were the same thickness as A. But in that case, the mass would be different and you would be comparing apples and oranges.
Apollo did the “BBQ Roll” to distribute heat evenly, but, by the above reasoning, the total heat absorbed would be greater than if it had not rotated.
The same should apply to a re-entry vehicle.
